# SQL query: selecting records and checking sum in joined table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table KIOSK

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kiosk` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `netId` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `countryId` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `cityId` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `long` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `venue` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `impressions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and a table PLACEMENT

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `placement` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `userId` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `adId` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kioskId` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `zoneId` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `dateBegin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateEnd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Placements mean publishing ad on a kiosk.
Each placement has a duration and dates for begining and ending of publishing.
It's allowed to compile a 240 seconds block of different ads on one kiosk, this
block will be rotated again and again during the day.

Now I need to select kiosk from specific city which has enought time in block to add advertisement there.

As I see it, I need to select kiosks and sum the durations of placements already added to that kiosks to check if I can add a placement record in table.

I tried something like

```
SELECT *, SUM(`placement`.`duration`) AS `d`
FROM `kiosk`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `placement` ON ((`cityId` = 'bac3d991-d13c-49c2-8563-8f974c75f6b9')
AND (`placement`.`kioskId` = `kiosk`.`id`)
AND ((`placement`.`dateBegin` BETWEEN 1333929600 AND 1333929600))
OR (`placement`.`dateEnd` BETWEEN 1333929600 AND 1333929600)))
GROUP BY `kiosk`.`id`
HAVING `d` <=225
OR `d` IS NULL
```

Here 225 is amount of possible used seconds in block (I want to place 15seconds ad in this example), and if there's no placement records for this kiosk I check `d` for being NULL

Seems I do everything wrong, because I receive the list of all kiosks no mather what is it's cityId or placements linked to it.

I would be thankful for any help

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to

```
SELECT *, SUM(`placement`.`duration`) AS `d`
FROM `kiosk`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `placement` ON (`kiosk`.`id` = `placement`.`kioskId`)
WHERE ((`cityId` = 'bac3d991-d13c-49c2-8563-8f974c75f6b9')
AND ((`placement`.`dateBegin` BETWEEN 1333929600 AND 1333929600))
OR (`placement`.`dateEnd` BETWEEN 1333929600 AND 1333929600)))
GROUP BY `kiosk`.`id`
HAVING `d` <=225
OR `d` IS NULL
```

Comment: This seems closer to what I need, but now it retirns no rows. I think it's because there is no matching records in placement table